# Stack Overflow Careers missing a space between our and annual in "ourannual user survey" and between at and careers in "atcareers@stackoverflow.com"

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Go to the Stack Overflow Careers [how to make a standout company](http://blog.careers.stackoverflow.com/2013/11/01/how-to-make-a-standout-company-page/) page.

Around 1/3 of the way down the page there is the following sentence

> We learned in ourannual user survey that the thing developers want most in a job is the ability to learn and grow.

There is a space missing between the words our and annual.

Later on in the same page there's also this.

> For more advice on maximising exposure to your job openings on Stack Overflow Careers, email us atcareers@stackoverflow.com.

Which needs a space between at and careers@stackoverflow.com

Comment: This is only when there is a link, because if you search for `our ann` with a space it find an instance (where it isn't linked).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whoops, all fixed now. Thanks!